# Extract table structure in hive

Tags: unix

I need to extract only the create table structure with columns alone.

```
 hive_table

show create table hive_table:
create table hive_table(id number,age number)
OUTPUTFORMAT
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcOutputFormat'
LOCATION  'hdfs:/path/'
```

I need only below

```
create table hive_table(id number,age number);
```

Comment: I am trying to use some think like this hive -e "show create table hive_table:"|sed -n -e '/^ *CREATE TABLE /{' -e ':L' -e '/) *$/{' -e 'p;d' -e '}' -e 'N; bL'    but getting error sed: -e expression #1, char 0: unmatched `{'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sed will be difficult in this case. Check this perl solution.

```
> cat hive_table.txt
show create table hive_table:
create table hive_table(id number,age number)
PARTITIONED BY ( year number )
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.MapredParquetInputFormat'
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.serde.ParquetHiveSerDe'
OUTPUTFORMAT
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcOutputFormat'
LOCATION  'hdfs:/path/'
TBLPROPERTIES (   'spark.sql.sources ....)
> perl -ne 'BEGIN{$x=qx(cat hive_table.txt);$x=~s/(.+)(create table.+?)(PARTITIONED BY|STORED AS INPUTFORMAT|ROW FORMAT SERDE|OUTPUTFORMAT|LOCATION|TBLPROPERTIES)(.*)/$2/osm; print $x ; exit } '
create table hive_table(id number,age number)
>
```

Comment: Here you are hardcoding PARTITIONED BY|STORED AS INPUTFORMAT|ROW FORMAT SERDE, i dont want that because no matter there can be anything after the create table ends.

Comment: what I gave is more of a generic solution.. your table can be partitioned or clustered, etc.. so you need to exclude all of them. Also your table column may contain datatypes like decimal(10,4), etc which will not allow you to parse between "(" and ")" in the create table syntax and get them.

Comment: for your case   perl -ne 'BEGIN{$x=qx(cat hive_table.txt);$x=~s/(.+)(create table.+?)(OUTPUTFORMAT)(.*)/$2/osm; print $x ; exit } '  will work

Comment: Yes it worked great. One more thing is it possible to append string at end something like CREATE TABLE `test`(
  `id` string COMMENT '',
  `age` string COMMENT '',
  `city` string COMMENT '') stored as orc

Comment: I am trying this but not working perl -ne 'BEGIN{$x=qx(cat test.txt);$x=~s/(.+)(CREATE TABLE.+?)(PARTITIONED BY|STRED AS INPUTFORMAT|ROW FORMAT SERDE|OUTPUTFORMAT|LOCATION|TBLPROPERTIES)(.*)/$2/osm; print $x +"stored as orc"; exit } '

Comment: you need to enclose them as single string for concatenation. Try this  perl -ne 'BEGIN{$x=qx(cat hive_table.txt);$x=~s/(.+)(CREATE TABLE.+?)(PARTITIONED BY|STRED AS INPUTFORMAT|ROW FORMAT SERDE|OUTPUTFORMAT|LOCATION|TBLPROPERTIES)(.*)/$2/osmi; print "$x stored as orc\n"; exit } '

Comment: or include it in the replacement of the regex as below   perl -ne 'BEGIN{$x=qx(cat hive_table.txt);$x=~s/(.+)(CREATE TABLE.+?)(PARTITIONED BY|STRED AS INPUTFORMAT|ROW FORMAT SERDE|OUTPUTFORMAT|LOCATION|TBLPROPERTIES)(.*)/$2 stored as orc/osmi; print "$x\n"; exit } '

Comment: if the solution works, please consider accepting the answer

Comment: Yes its working perfrectly but what if i had multple create statement in same test.file

Comment: in that case one-liner will not be sufficient. You have to write a extended perl script with a while loop performing lot of regex operations. BTW.. that should be a new question.

Comment: I have posted the answer where i am stuck

Comment: hi..post it as a new question.. not as one more answer in the same question. I'm working on it.  btw.. please consider accepting this solution.

Comment: I have posted new question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52531293/extract-multiple-create-table-statement-in-hive

Comment: please check the answer

Answer (score 0):

I am trying like this

```
#!/bin/bash
rm -f tableNames.txt
rm -f HiveTableDDL.txt
beeline --showHeader=false --outputformat=tsv2 -u jdbc:hive2:// -n hive -e "show tables like 'test*';" > tableNames.txt 
wait
while read LINE
do
   beeline --showHeader=false --outputformat=tsv2 -u jdbc:hive2:// -n hive -e "show create table $LINE" | perl -ne 'BEGIN{$x=qx(cat test.txt);$x=~s/(.+)(create table.+?)(ROW FORMAT SERDE|STORED AS INPUTFORMAT|ROW FORMAT SERDE|OUTPUTFORMAT|LOCATION|TBLPROPERTIES)(.*)/$2/osm; print "$x STORED AS ORC\n" ; exit } '
   printf  ";\n\n" 
done < tableNames.txt >> HiveTableDDL.txt
rm -f tableNames.txt
echo "Table DDL generated"
```