# Extract multiple create table statement in hive

Tags: unix

I need to extract create table statments from below code.

```
    #!/bin/bash
rm -f tableNames.txt
rm -f HiveTableDDL.txt
beeline --showHeader=false --outputformat=tsv2 -u jdbc:hive2:// -n hive -e "show tables like 'test*';" > tableNames.txt 
wait
while read LINE
do
   beeline --showHeader=false --outputformat=tsv2 -u jdbc:hive2:// -n hive -e "show create table $LINE" | perl -ne 'BEGIN{$x=qx(cat test.txt);$x=~s/(.+)(create table.+?)(ROW FORMAT SERDE|STORED AS INPUTFORMAT|ROW FORMAT SERDE|OUTPUTFORMAT|LOCATION|TBLPROPERTIES)(.*)/$2/osm; print "$x STORED AS ORC\n" ; exit } '
   printf  ";\n\n" 
done < tableNames.txt >> HiveTableDDL.txt
rm -f tableNames.txt
echo "Table DDL generated"
```

I wanted to have something like below

```
CREATE TABLE `test`(
  `id` string COMMENT '',
  `age` string COMMENT '',
  `city` string COMMENT '') stored as orc;

CREATE TABLE `test_2`(
  `id` string COMMENT '',
  `age` string COMMENT '',
  `city` string COMMENT '') stored as orc;
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if this works for you.

```
> cat hive_table.txt2
show create table hive_table:
create table hive_table(id number,age number)
OUTPUTFORMAT
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcOutputFormat'
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.MapredParquetInputFormat'
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.serde.ParquetHiveSerDe'
LOCATION  'hdfs:/path/'
TBLPROPERTIES (   'spark.sql.sources ....)
show create table hive_table2:
create table hive_table2(id number,age number)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.serde.ParquetHiveSerDe'
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcOutputFormat'
LOCATION  'hdfs:/path/'
TBLPROPERTIES (   'spark.sql.sources ....)
show create table hive_table3:
create table hive_table3(id number,age number)
OUTPUTFORMAT
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcOutputFormat'
LOCATION  'hdfs:/path/'
TBLPROPERTIES (   'spark.sql.sources ....)
>
> hive_table.pl hive_table.txt2
create table hive_table(id number,age number)
 stored as orc
create table hive_table2(id number,age number)
 stored as orc
create table hive_table3(id number,age number)
 stored as orc
>
```

The script is

```
> cat hive_table.pl
#!/usr/bin/perl
$file=$ARGV[0];
$x=qx(cat $file);
while($x=~m/(.+?)(create table.+?)(CREATE TABLE.+?)(PARTITIONED BY|STRED AS INPUTFORMAT|ROW FORMAT SERDE|OUTPUTFORMAT|LOCATION|TBLPROPERTIES)(.*)/iosm)
{
$x=$5;
$table_desc=$3;
print "$table_desc stored as orc\n";
}

>
```

EDIT1:

```
> cat hive_table.pl
#!/usr/bin/perl
$file=$ARGV[0];
$x=qx(cat $file);
while($x=~m/(.+?)(create table.+?)(PARTITIONED BY|STRED AS INPUTFORMAT|ROW FORMAT SERDE|OUTPUTFORMAT|LOCATION|TBLPROPERTIES)(.*)/iosm)
{
$x=$4;
$table_desc=$2;
print "$table_desc stored as orc\n";
}

>
```

**EDIT2:**

```
> cat hive_table.txt3
create table hive_table(id number,age number)
OUTPUTFORMAT
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcOutputFormat'
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.MapredParquetInputFormat'
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.serde.ParquetHiveSerDe'
LOCATION  'hdfs:/path/'
TBLPROPERTIES (   'spark.sql.sources ....)
create table hive_table2(id number,age number)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.serde.ParquetHiveSerDe'
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcOutputFormat'
LOCATION  'hdfs:/path/'
TBLPROPERTIES (   'spark.sql.sources ....)
create table hive_table3(id number,age number)
OUTPUTFORMAT
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcOutputFormat'
LOCATION  'hdfs:/path/'
TBLPROPERTIES (   'spark.sql.sources ..)
>  hive_table.pl hive_table.txt3
create table hive_table(id number,age number)
 stored as orc
create table hive_table2(id number,age number)
 stored as orc
create table hive_table3(id number,age number)
 stored as orc
/etl/stage3/CAM/AN06599/work_2018/stack> cat hive_table.pl
#!/usr/bin/perl
$file=$ARGV[0];
$x=qx(cat $file);
$x="dummy".$x."dummy";
while($x=~m/(.+?)(create table.+?)(PARTITIONED BY|STRED AS INPUTFORMAT|ROW FORMAT SERDE|OUTPUTFORMAT|LOCATION|TBLPROPERTIES)(.*)/iosm)
{
$x=$4;
$table_desc=$2;
print "$table_desc stored as orc\n";
}

>
```

Comment: and also if you have any of the columns name as location or outputformat.. like that will create problem

Comment: check the EDIT1 .

Comment: As i said you will have a problem if you have column as location or output. something like create table hive_table2(id number,age number,id_location string)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.serde.ParquetHiveSerDe'
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcOutputFormat'
LOCATION  'hdfs:/path/'

Comment: my EDIT1 should have worked for you...can you update the question with sample file with this scenario.

Comment: ok.. the very firstline starts with "create table.." so I have to add some dummy text and loop through.. check my EDIT2

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180926/discussion-between-user2672739-and-stack0114106).

Comment: If you have create table hive_table3(id number,age number, id_location ) then you will get create table hive_table2(id number,age numberi,id_ stored as orc
create table hive_table3(id number,age number)
 stored as orc